# How to Scrape data from pop-ups (i need to scrape data that is only visible once I click the popup, which is not a link)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm an absolute beginner in Python.
I need to scrape data from this website, which is a directory of professors

Some of the data are visible without the need to click, (names and school etc)
However I need to scrape email, department info as well.

I've been searching on the internet for the whole day and I don't know how to do it
Could anyone plz help?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you check the [network activity](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/), you'll see that the data is dynamically loaded from google spreadsheets. You can retrieve the [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRb-Mr1V5FMUBKTE4Nb_u6IXsQOQ7n9NTBHF_MEpVPPV5ZZXEsoxgczGfrwu1Xr5IrUG54c7oVbEH3F/pub?gid=0&single=true&output=csv) directly without scraping.